# ArcGIS Pro: Select by location result varies w.r.t system being used

Tags: arcgis-pro

We are getting different results if we run the "Select by location" tool in ArcGIS Pro (same version 2.1.1) for same two layers but in different machines. We didn't assign any tolerance level and the units are kept "Unknown". How is it possible ? Does it have to do anything ArcGIS pro settings ?.

Edit: Attached is the screenshot of parameters used. Left the values to default

[image]

Does it have to do anything with M tolerance and M Resolution ?

Comment: Are you talking about coordinate systems or something else?

Comment: Both are in same coordinate system

Comment: Your question says “different systems” but your comment says “same coordinate system”.

Comment: have edited the question. Meant to say different computer systems

Comment: Are you using the same project on both machines?  What parameter values are you using for the tool on each machine?

Comment: Edited and attached a screenshot of parameters used. Not same project. Same shapefiles copied to different machines